# How to work with SOAP attachment?

Tags: .net, soap, attachment

I need to work with SOAP attachment in .NET, if anyone know how to do that please let me know with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to be more clear about what you mean when you say "SOAP Attachment". If you are referring to "SOAP with Attachments", then you are referring to an obsolete technology which is not supported by .NET.